# Android UsageStatsManager: queryEvents return null for Android R+

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions, usagestatsmanager

The issue is pretty clear, I want to query which app is currently being executed with queryEvents and looping over the running type events, unfortunately, this does not work for Android R+ devices.
Per Android documentation, we need to add two system permissions:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission"/>
```

But, even with these permissions, the query still returns nothing for Android 11 and onwards devices.
the query function is also pretty simple:

```
(context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager).also {

    val usageStatsManager: UsageStatsManager = it
    val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val queryEvents =
        usageStatsManager.queryEvents(currentTimeMillis - (1000*60*10), currentTimeMillis)
    val event = UsageEvents.Event()
    var str = ""
    while (queryEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
        queryEvents.getNextEvent(event)
        Timber.d(event.className)
        if (event.eventType == UsageEvents.Event.ACTIVITY_RESUMED) {
            str = event.packageName
        }
    }
```

}